# effect of increase worker thread in gensim word2vec

Tags: multithreading, gensim, word2vec

I'm trying to train a gensim sgns model and in the process I measure the loss during which I'm calculating as

```
loss = model.running_training_loss / model.corpus_count,
```

however, I noticed that if I change my worker thread I get different losses keeping all other parameters same. Especially if I keep my worker thread a 1 I get a really high loss and If I increase threads I get less loss. An instance

```
thread  loss
worker=1  20.40519721
worker=10   2.714875407
worker=16  1.239528453
```

Answer (score 0):

Up through gensim 3.5.0, the loss value reported may not be very sensible, only resetting the tally each call to train(), rather than each internal epoch. There are some fixes forthcoming in this issue:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/pull/2135

What version of gensim are you using, and what is your code doing to collect the loss data?

Comment: I'm using gensim 3.6.0, I'm trying to create an early stopping mechanism based upon the loss. After each epoch I store the loss as mentioned above and store it such that if there no less loss in next consecutive epoch I check next 3 epochs and in the process I save the best model where I get the least loss. But the problem what I'm seeing is the number of workers threads as to why do I get such a large variance in the loss when I change the worker threads ..?

Comment: It's possible there's something amiss with your not-shown-here training code, or the collecting/reporting of the varying loss values. But perhaps also there's a bug in gensim 3.6.0. If you can make a self-contained code/data example showing extreme changes in reported-loss with different `worker` values, you should report it as a bug in the `gensim` github issue tracker.